# `<input type='file' accept='audio/*' />` is not respected on Chrome 73, Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

When I try the below snippet in Android Chrome 73 not only does it not narrow down the file selection to the `accept` attribute, but the `file.name` that comes back does not have a file extension on it.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
addEventListener('load', function(){
document.getElementById('test').onchange = function(){
  var files = this.files, file;
  if(files.length){
    file = files[0];
    alert('file.type = '+file.type+'; file.name = '+file.name+';');
  }
  else{
    alert('No file was selected');
  }
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```html
<input id='test' type='file' accept='audio/*' />
```

Odd, that it totally works if I change `accept='audio/*'` to `accept='video/*'`. Of course, I want an audio file. So my question is, why is this happening? Is Google that bad at their job?